# Flatten a jagged multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need help flattening an array like this:

```
[1,2,[2,3],[5,[6,1],4],7]
```

I want it to be something like

```
[1,2,2,3,5,6,1,4,7].
```

I have searched something like this, and found `[].concat.apply`, but it will only take care of the two dimensional arrays.

I also want to use an algorithm that will work for any jagged multi dimensional arrays. Please help. Thx

Comment: You might want to tell us what programming language you're using.

Comment: sry i meant javascript

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to take a dependency on [lodash](https://lodash.com) and use the [`flattenDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep) function.

```
_.flattenDeep([1,2,[2,3],[5,[6,1],4],7])
// [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7 ]
```

If you want to write your own function, you might want to peek at the lodash implementation.

In pseudo-code, here's a recursive approach:

```
result = []
function flatten(array)
  for each element in array
    if element is array
      flatten(element)
    else
      result.append(element)
```

**EDIT**

Here's a "by-hand" approach, though I'd definitely recommend relying on the better-tested lodash implementation.

```js
function flatten(arr, result) {
  if (result === undefined) {
    result = [];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      flatten(arr[i], result);
    } else {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(flatten([1, 2, [2, 3], [5, [6, 1], 4], 7]));

// Output:
// [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 7 ]
```

Comment: thx, but this question relates to a problem on a website. i can only solve it with vanilla javascript

Comment: @nova_n Why can't you use lodash?

Comment: Just add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>` to the `<head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: This site only allows vanila javascript for training.

Comment: Thanx for the by hand solution tho

Comment: @nova_n: You should really make _some_ attempt to solve these codewars questions on your own. You will learn much more by looking for a solution, experimenting with some code to see what happens, tracing through your code in the JavaScript debugger, and studying the language in more depth. Asking for someone to write out the solution for you may get you through the codewars tests, but you won't learn nearly as much that way.

Comment: i know. this was only part of a question. i wanted to flatten an array so i could itterate thru values in deeply nested arrays. The project was about counting strings in objects. some of the properties were objects, arrays, and strings

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `concat.apply` thing in a loop to handle deeply nested arrays:

```
while (a.some(Array.isArray))
    a = [].concat.apply([], a)
```

or in the ES6 syntax:

```
while (a.some(Array.isArray)) 
    a = [].concat(...a);
```